# MySQL Rollup Puzzle

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
select 
        members_categories.category_desc as 'membership_type',
    SUM( CASE payment_method WHEN 'Bank Transfer' THEN amount_paid ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Bank Transfer',
    SUM( CASE payment_method WHEN 'Cash' THEN amount_paid ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Cash', 
    SUM( CASE payment_method WHEN 'Cheque' THEN amount_paid ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Cheque', 
    SUM( CASE payment_method WHEN 'Credit Card' THEN amount_paid ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Credit Card', 
    SUM( CASE payment_method WHEN 'Direct Debit' THEN amount_paid ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Direct Debit', 
    SUM( CASE payment_method WHEN 'PayPal' THEN amount_paid ELSE 0 END ) AS 'PayPal', 
    SUM( CASE payment_method WHEN 'Salary Deduction' THEN amount_paid ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Salary Deduction', 
    SUM( CASE payment_method WHEN 'Standing Order' THEN amount_paid ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Standing Order', 
    SUM( amount_paid ) AS 'Total' 
    FROM members_main, members_categories, members_payments  
    WHERE members_categories.category_code=members_main.membership_type and members_main.contact_id=members_payments.contact_id and members_payments.payment_date between '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31' 
     GROUP BY membership_type With ROLLUP
```

Which returns:

[image]

As you can see from above the ROLLUP total at the bottom shows a descrption of the membership_type field of the last row returned.  Is there a way to replace this with the word **Total**?

Comment: Cool did not know about `ROLLUP`

Comment: Nope. There's no such option in the mysql syntax. You'll have to detect the duplicate the name, on the understanding that the FIRST instance of the rolled-up field is the original value, and the subsequent value is the rollup.

Comment: by documentation, that cell value should be `NULL`. Something is fishy here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc. I am a MySQL newbie, is there any way you can help me with that code?

Comment: @STTLCU Thats what I thought too reading up on the ROLLUP command - don't understand why it's doing it.

Comment: Well, I’d say fishy is that you select a column value (members_categories.category_desc) that is not part of the GROUPing, which is illegal in strict SQL, and only tolerated by MySQL. That MySQL then selects a “random” value is documented, and might cause the effect seen here as well.

Comment: @CBroe (members_categories.category_desc) is just aliased by membership_type, which is where the group by is based on. It should work...

Comment: Oh, yeah, overlooked that, thanks.

Comment: What mySQL version? What is the actual GROUP BY expression in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use IFNULL for this:

```
 select 
    IFNULL(members_categories.category_desc, 'Total') as 'membership_type',

 ...
 GROUP BY membership_type With ROLLUP
```

This does what you need. If you were being totally ANSI compliant, you'd use

```
 GROUP BY members_categories.category_desc With ROLLUP
```

If you are using more than one item in the GROUP BY clause, you need to handle them all with IFNULL.  For example, from your SqlFiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8818d/16/0

```
SELECT IFNULL(product,'GROUP TOTAL') AS product,     <--- group by term
       IFNULL(year, 'YEAR TOTAL') as year,           <--- group by term
       SUM(amount) 
  FROM test_rollup
 GROUP BY year, product WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it and got the same result. Something weird going on I think

Comment: For some reason its definitely not working here - I have no idea why. Could it be something to do with the data?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it must be a data issue then?

Comment: See my edit. You didn't mention `year` in your original post.